# Folder Options isn't accessible

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, 64-bit, user-folders

As shown in this screen shot:
[image]

Folder and search options is for some reason greyed-out, videlicet one cannot access them in any probable manner.

What could be the possible cause and solution to this unpleasant problem ?

Comment: Does it open if you run **Control Folders** ? Did you run malware scan ?

Comment: It doesn't open from everywhere. Well I once had a virus messing up with the registry, but I made sure that I will not allow this again. Malwarebytes~

Comment: can you verify the registry ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ggL4M.png

Comment: Yes it is exists. However changing the registry didn't fix it, but local user policy did !

Comment: Hiding Folder Options was tricks malwares & viruses used in 90's. Not sure what you had or still have...Malwarebytes chameleon is what I prefer then just Malwarebytes

Comment: I have been turning it off, I haven't scanned since years so it is very possible that it is a malware... Anyway changing the policy prevented it of hiding it anymore ..as it appears.